# KARATE integration with SauceLabs

Tags: karate, saucelabs

I would like to understand if,
 - it makes sense to have Karate integration with SauceLabs
 - Benefits if that is an Yes

Also, if i want to implement the integration what is the approach i should use.

I am planning to mimic the similar implementation using Selenium remote web driver. Please let me know if this is the only approach that can be taken or there is any other way out for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if SauceLabs conforms to the spec - refer to the documentation for `webDriverSession`: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#webdriversession

Note that this has been proven to work with Zalenium: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#webdriverurl

And also AWS Device Farm: https://twitter.com/ptrthomas/status/1222790566598991873

Please note that if you are ok to use only Chrome, the Docker approach may give you a better experience, but you can decide: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-chrome

EDIT - also see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64682293/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63270092/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65644566/143475

Comment: thank you for the details. Is this applicable for API or UI? Currently I am only having API scripts. Does that make sense to have this integration?

Comment: @JishanAli this depends on whether SauceLabs has support for API testing and I have no idea about it - so maybe you should ask them. If you want my opinion - no, it does not make sense to use SauceLabs for API tests, parallel execution via CI should be sufficient.