# Running karate tests on chrome with chromedriver inside docker

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I would like to run my karate tests using the chromedriver and chrome present in a docker container. How can this be achieved ? I could only find the documentation on the native version of chrome [here](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Docker#examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only support chrome native via Docker. Note that you can use existing Selenium "Grid" infra, for e.g see these:

https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-devicefarm-demo

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60992292/143475

You can consider creating your own Docker image (which is very common) or use an existing "Selenium flavored" one. Do note that Karate is open-source. Maybe you would be interested to contribute this Docker container :)

Comment: If I use Zalenium to connect to Sauce labs to run IE. How should the driver config look like ?

Comment: @CVA I haven't used Sauce Labs - this is what works on localhost: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#webdriverurl