# karate-dsl: options --window-size and --incognito is not working for chromeDriver

Tags: karate

Both the options --window-size or --incognito are not working with chromedriver. However the same options works perfectly with type chrome. I tried option --start-maximized but this also not working. I have maintained the driver configutation in karate-config.js.

```
function fn() {
    let env = karate.env;
    karate.configure('ssl', true);
    karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
    
    if (!env) {
        //Java function to read browser value from properties
        env = Java.type('examples.users.utilities.ConfigReader').read("app.target.browser").trim();
    }

    const config = {
        env: env,
    };

    switch (env) {
        case "chrome":
            //Java function to get screen resolution/dimension
            //Java function to get screen chrome driver file path
            karate.configure('driver', {
                type: 'chromedriver',
                executable: Java.type('examples.users.utilities.Miscellaneous').getDriverFilePath() + "chromedriver.exe",
                addOptions: ["--window-size=\"" + Java.type('examples.users.utilities.Miscellaneous').getWindowResolution() + "\"", "--disable-extensions"]
            });
            break;

        case "firefox":
            karate.configure('driver', {
                type: 'firefox',
                addOptions: ["--incognito", "--window-size=\"" + Java.type('examples.users.utilities.Miscellaneous').getWindowResolution() + "\"", "--disable-extensions"]
            });
            break;

        default:
            karate.log('Given browser is not present');
    }
    return config;
}
```

Here the Feature file.

```
Feature: Launch browser example 1
  
  Scenario: Open google and enter text to search
    Given driver 'https://www.google.com'
    When input("input[type=text]", 'karate')
    And submit()
```

Below are folder structure and complete source can be found [here](https://github.com/dipakkumar1225/karatePractice.git).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, those options only work for `chrome`. This is an area where we welcome contributions and research.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62700642/143475