# Karate - UI Testing - When using Zalenium Safari and MSEDGE immediately error on driver/session call => no capabilities found

Tags: karate, saucelabs

git project: https://github.com/jbart18/karate_testing

I'm trying to simplify having the main browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge & Safari) working via Zalenium. It seems the most simple approach and have been able to get chrome and firefox (gecko driver) running/working straight away.

The problem lies within Edge and Safari and the inability to submit capabilities in the session request.

I am running on Windows 10 professional and have been able to get tests working for:
edge: through specifying the executable path and setting the webdriver session
safari: running macos via VM and then specifying the executable path (a big hassle - though I will need to either debug safari issues or when needing xcode for mobile testing)

I am hoping to simplify e2e testing using zalenium. Please help.
I followed "https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/#try-it" to get zalenium up and running

request:
* configure driver = { type: 'safaridriver', start: false, webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'}

Error:
"error": "unknown error",
"message": "Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: safari}",

However when I change the driver configuration statement"

```
* def session = { capabilities: { browserName: "safari" } }
* configure driver = { type: 'safaridriver', webDriverSession: '#(session)', start: false, showDriverLog: true, webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'}
```

Error:

### HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /wd/hub/session. Reason:

```
    Server Error
```

#### Caused by:

java.io.IOException: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: No capabilities found in request: {"capabilities":{"browserName":"safari"}}

I am unable to get either edge or safari via zalenium up and running.
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

jbart18

Answer (score 2):

I am using Edge and Safari browsers of Saucelabs through Zalenium as below.

**Microsoft Edge**

```
{type : msedgedriver, webDriverSession : {capabilities : {browserName : MicrosoftEdge}, desiredCapabilities : {browserName : MicrosoftEdge}}, start : false, webDriverUrl : https://username:password@your_zalenium_host.com/wd/hub}
```

**Safari**

```
{type : safaridriver, webDriverSession : {capabilities : {browserName : safari}, desiredCapabilities : {browserName : safari}}, start : false, webDriverUrl : https://username:password@your_zalenium_host.com/wd/hub}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, @Prashant Patil - I was hoping for a solution which didnt require a paid subscription but it seems currently that isnt available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the capabilities for Edge are hard to figure out. Meanwhile do take a look at this demo project for AWS Device Farm that may give you some ideas: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-devicefarm-demo

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Peter, though the AWS device farm example is utilizing chrome - is it possible to inject the required capabilities params into the configure driver statement to have safari/firefox working via zalenium? (p.S I've since attached a sample project - at top of the summary.

Comment: @jbart18 - yes but the problem is you need to know what exactly to pass. one way is to study what other ui frameworks do. here is a relevant thread: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/924 - also someone recently contributed edge support so I've pinged that person via slack to look over here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/pull/1302

Comment: apologies Peter Thomas - after subsequent reading                 
it's not an issue with Karate or the call but a limitation of the Zalenium grid. It runs/supports chrome/firefox tests through docker selenium. But... if you need a different browser, zalenium routes to a testing provider such as sauce labs or browser stack. Not ideal as they are all paid options.

Comment: @jbart18 many thanks for the update, this will help others who land on this page 