# Unable to procedd with UI Automation even after WebSocket success message in Terminal [Karate UI - Playwright Integration]

Tags: karate

Followed the Documentation https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#playwright to integrate Karate with Playwright for UI Automation.

Below 2 setups are working fine either
with executuble script :

```
 * configure driver = { type: 'playwright', start: true, headless: false, executable: '.../ui_automation/playwright.sh' }
```

or with direct url :

```
configure driver = { type: 'playwright', start: false, playwrightUrl: 'ws://localhost:4444/c953265076caf23f548deeddbc66ac190' }.
```

Terminal Output

`12:06:46.455 [main] DEBUG c.i.k.d.playwright_1708497404377 - playwright server url ready: ws://localhost:4444/9c7c766e1fcd8747a74f335890acfc53 12:06:46.788 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG c.i.k.http.WebSocketClientHandler - websocket client connected`

But later on Chromium or firefox browser getting initiated but karate scenrio Script is not executing and also not providing any logs or timeout error.

Please let me know if i missing something here and kindly help me to execute the karate script through playwright!  Thanks

Able to see duplicate issue : [unable to execute karate script through playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68490053/unable-to-execute-karate-script-through-playwright)

here but not working for me as expected .

I am using latest karate version as well

Comment: this is old information. please refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2291 and should be testable in 1.5.0.RC3