# Karate webdriver calls are failing in selenium grid 4 with UnsupportedCommandException

Tags: karate, selenium4

Karate scripts are failing when we point to Selenium grid 4. If we point to selenium grid 3 or earlier to 4 versions are working.

Tested with karate 1.1.0 and Simple **Example 1** navigates to GitHub and Google Search example.

Exception :  "org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST \u002fsession\u002f5d0b30168667aba9b10a01f9091d22cb\u002fexecute\u002fsync.

In Grid 4, a major under-the-hood (or architectural) change is that WebDriver APIs in Selenium 4 follow the W3C (World Wide Web Consortium) in its implementation.

For Selenium versions earlier than Selenium 4, the JSON Wire Protocol was used for communicating with the web browser. ​As the Selenium Client libraries (i.e., Client) use the JSON protocol, and the web browser uses the W3C protocol, API encoding and decoding was involved in the entire process.

Want to understand is it impacting the webdriver execution?

Any workaround can u suggest?

Comment: I request you to contribute code in this area. As far as we know, we support the W3C protocol. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65644566/143475 But you never know, there could be bugs :) I look forward to seeing your research and contributions !